# Chromecast performance differs between devices

Tags: wi-fi, networking, internet, chromecast

I have a Chromecast in my bedroom and a dual-band router in the living room. The connection is solid enough that it will connect, and on my Moto X using the 5GHz radio can play 1080p video without issue or delay from Plex, YouTube, Netflix, etc.

However, when I try to cast these very same services from my Galaxy Tab 2 which uses the 2.4GHz radio, I notice playback stuttering in Plex and degraded video in Netflix and YouTube.

My question is this: why does the performance of my Chromecast differ depending on the device which is sending it requests? I thought it functioned much like a Google TV or Player where it would simply "open" (or be sent) an app and data request? Or is the information that it's playing coming from my Android device?

I feel like there's a clarity issue on Google's side, as I've found no documentation on this particular subject, and don't have the patience to sift through the developer documentation.

**Update:** I connected my Moto X to the 2.4GHz band as well to see if [@Eldarathis](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/981/eldarerathis)' idea was correct, but the video still loaded just fine. I'm convinced that the poor performance of my tablet is somehow affecting the performance of the Chromecast.

Comment: Possibly it's because the Chromecast is 2.4 GHz only, so you're getting more interference on that band when it has to both stream and communicate back and forth with the Tab all on the same band.

Comment: @eldarerathis I've updated my post accordingly